# Access 2007-Search Form does not return all values because of a blank field--Can't seem to find the LIKE that matches

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, ms-access-2007

First of all thank you for your time and sorry if some issues are unclear, this is my first message here.

I'm having a problem with a custom search form I have made on ACCESS 2007.

Here is my database:

[image: Database dump]

Here is my search form:

[image: search form]

The main issue I have is that whenever I enter values in firstname, lastername, address, etc.
It works totally fine.

But as soon as I get to work phone, mobile or email, it doesn't show me "Florence Fluflo" because her fields are blank for these categories.

Now I have tried in the "Criteria" of the field Work phone to put these:

- `LIKE ""`
- `LIKE "*" & [Forms]![frm_search]![WorkPhone1] & "*" OR "IsNull"`
- `=" " OR =""`
- `LIKE " "`
- `LIKE "*"`

Nothing works... and it's pretty weird because I have done SQL and the SQL statement looks perfectly fine:

```
SELECT CLIENTS.First_name, 
       CLIENTS.Surname, 
       CLIENTS.Address, 
       CLIENTS.Suburb, 
       CLIENTS.Postcode, 
       CLIENTS.Home_phone, 
       CLIENTS.Work_phone
FROM CLIENTS
WHERE (((CLIENTS.First_name) Like "*" & [Forms]![frm_search]![Firstname1] & "*") 
    AND ((CLIENTS.Surname) Like "*" & [Forms]![frm_search]![LastName1] & "*") 
    AND ((CLIENTS.Address) Like "*" & [Forms]![frm_search]![Address1] & "*") 
    AND ((CLIENTS.Suburb) Like "*" & [Forms]![frm_search]![Suburb1] & "*") 
    AND ((CLIENTS.Postcode) Like "*" & [Forms]![frm_search]![Postcode1] & "*") 
    AND ((CLIENTS.Home_phone) Like "*" & [Forms]![frm_search]![HomePhone1] & "*") 
    AND **((CLIENTS.Work_phone) Like "*" & [Forms]![frm_search]![WorkPhone1] & "*" OR (CLIENTS.Work_phone) Like ""))**;
```

Comment: @ScottJShea: good job editing so far; though don't hesitate to inline images for low-reputation users if you think it'll improve the post, and please [remove "thanks"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) and similar from posts. (I wouldn't _reject_ for that, but others might.) Thanks!

Comment: @sarnold Thank you for the tips and the link to the Meta site

Comment: Shouldn't it be `OR (CLIENTS.Work_phone) IS NULL`? The sheer amount of parentheses in the above query is mind-numbing (yes, I know that's Access doing that! ;)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write `"IsNull"` (in quotes), it will be considered as a string. So, the proper way to verify if a field is null would be like this `IS NULL`
That means all you need to do for your thing to work is to write

```
OR IS NULL
```

after your `LIKE` statement