# SQL Search Statement

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm currently using MS Access 2007 to build a database system. Using the form below I want to be able to search the database for one of the following criteria. Call ID, Phone_No, Company_Name, Cell_No, Zip Code.

I've seen various SQL Statements that would be used in an individual search. Such as the one below:

```
SELECT ID
FROM Calls_DB
WHERE ID = '1';
```

Whilst looking at similar questions i found the code which works for me on this page 
[Access 2007-Search Form does not return all values because of a blank field--Can't seem to find the LIKE that matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814016/access-2007-search-form-does-not-return-all-values-because-of-a-blank-field-can)

However how can I get the results to be displayed within the list box using SQL?

[image]

Comment: It's not clear whether this is a SQL question or an MS Access coding question.

Comment: Apologies i left the SQL tag in by accident. Using a modified version of the above link, i just need the results of the search function to be displayed in the list box.

Comment: Please, review this entry:
[Design an Access Form with Dynamic SQL as Recordsource][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989301/design-an-access-form-with-dynamic-sql-as-recordsource/20990311

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below query will help you.

```
SELECT * FROM Calls_DB
  WHERE IIF(ISNULL(ID),’’, CSTR(ID)) LIKE ‘%Call ID Value%’
  AND IIF(ISNULL(Phone_No),’’, CSTR(Phone_No)) LIKE ‘%Phone_No Value%’
  AND IIF(ISNULL(Company_Name),’’, CSTR(Company_Name)) LIKE 
      ‘%Company_Name Value%’
  AND IIF(ISNULL(Cell_No),’’, CSTR(Cell_No)) LIKE ‘%Cell_No Value%’
  AND IIF(ISNULL(Zip),’’, CSTR(Zip)) LIKE ‘%Zip Value%’
  AND IIF(ISNULL(Code),’’, CSTR(Code)) LIKE ‘%Code Value%’
```

After getting query result in record set(rec) run below code

```
 ListBoxName.ColumnCount = rec.fields.count
 ListBoxName.RowSource = rec.OpenRecordset
```

for more details please refer [http://www.access-[programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=107277]]

Comment: How would i get the results from the above statement into the listbox?